# Masscan & Nmap script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm currently studying pen-testing and in the exercise book "Mastering kali linux for advanced penetration testing-second edition" and the script they give for Masscan & Nmap(combined) is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function helptext {
echo "enter the massnmap with the file input with list of IP address      ranges"
}
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo  "Sorry cannot understand the command"
helptext>&2
exit 1
elif [ ! -s $1 ]; then
echo "ooops it is empty"
helptext>&2
exit 1
fi

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
echo "I assunme you are running as root"
helptext>&2
exit 1
fi
for range in $(cat $1); do
  store=$(echo $range | sed -e 's/\//_g')
  echo "I am trying to create a store to dump now hangon"
  mkdir -p pwd/$store;
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 60000 -j DROP;
  echo -e "\n alright lets fire masscan ****"
  masscan --open --banners --source-port 60000 -p0-65535 --max-rate 15000          -oBpwd/$store/masscan.bin $range; masscan --read$
  if [ ! -s ./results/$store/masscan-output.txt ]; then
      echo "Thanks for wasting time"
    else
    awk'/open/ {print $4, $3, $2, $1}' ./results/$store/masscan-output.txt | awk'
                                                          /.+/{
                                                          if (! ($1 in Val)) { Key[++i] = $1; }
                                                          Val[$1] = Val[$1] $2 ",";
                                                          END{
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {                        printf("%s:%s\n%s", Key[j], Val[Key[j]], (j == i) ? "" : "\n");                       }
                                                                                    }'>}./results/$store/hostsalive.csv
for ips found in $(cat ./results/$store/hostsalive.csv); do
  IP=$(echo $TARGET | awk -F: '{print $1}');
  PORT=$(echo $TARGET | awk -F: '{print$2}' | sed's/,$//');
  FILENAME=$(echo $IP | awk'{print "nmap_"$1}');
  nmap -vv -sV --version-intensity 5 -sT -O --max-rate 5000 -Pn -T3 -p     $PORT -oA ./results/$store/$FILENAME $IP;
                                                                   done
                                                                 fi
                                                                 done
```

I wrote it out by hand just to make sure it was done correctly and when i run after doing chmod +x (filename.sh) it i get:
(running ./filename.sh) i get "Sorry cannot understand the command
enter the massnmap with the file input with list of IP address ranges"

(running ./filename.sh ipran.txt) i get "./anyname.sh: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `found'
./anyname.sh: line 37:`for ips found in $(cat ./results/$store/hostsalive.csv); do'"

i am meant to get "I am trying to create a store to dump now hangon" "alright lets fire masscan ****"

i have tried using different ips(in my ipran.txt file) 
any help would be greatly appreciated 
OS used -Kali linux

Comment: Probably you should change the `for` line to this one:
`for TARGET in $(cat /results/$store/hostsalive.csv); do`
The syntax you're using in that line is incorrectly written.

Comment: thank you, i will try that, can you explain how it's incorrect? i was really confused as that's exactly whats in the book i'm using to study. Thanks again for the comment :)

Comment: i just tried it and worked thanks again!

Comment: As Ardit already told: "The syntax you're using in that line is incorrectly written." The `for` loop should've the syntax: `for` _variable_ `in` _string_ `; do`... It performs the body (from `do` til `done`) for each word in the _string_ assigned to _variable_. (See e.g. [tldp.org/HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html)). Thus, `for ips found in` describes literally what should be done but is _not_ correct bash syntax. Like Ardit, I would suspect the `ips found` has to be replaced by `TARGET` according to its usage in the `for` loop body.

Comment: "i was really confused as that's exactly whats in the book i'm using to study." -> Well, the book seems to have a mistake. You might report it to the author... (Don't forget to ask for refunding.)

Comment: @Scheff thank you for explaining and yes i did what he said and it worked fine.